# How to get Pickup location code for an Order

Tags: msi, multi-source-inventory, store-pickup, instore-pickup

An order is placed with the instore_pickup Shipping method, but I cannot find the store code from where the order is supposed to be picked up. There is no information for this in sales_order or sales_shipment tables.

How can I get the pickup location store code or information by the given order Id?

Answer (score 1):

After checking through the DB and Magento MSI modules, I found out that `instore_pickup` information is not saved in `sales_order` tables, but it is saved in `inventory_pickup_location_order` table with only straight forward columns

```
`order_id`,`pickup_location_code`
```

And to get the pickup location code by an order_id, MSI module `Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales` is providing the following ResouceModel method.

> Magento\InventoryInStorePickupSales\Model\ResourceModel\OrderPickupLocation\GetPickupLocationCodeByOrderId::execute(int
> $orderId)

So, to get the pickup location code by order_id, you can use the following way in your class/code.

```
use Magento\InventoryInStorePickupSales\Model\ResourceModel\OrderPickupLocation\GetPickupLocationCodeByOrderId;

class GetPickupLocationForOrder
{
    /**
     * @var GetPickupLocationCodeByOrderId
     */
    private $getPickupLocationByOrderId;


    public function __construct(
        GetPickupLocationCodeByOrderId $getPickupLocationByOrderId
    ) {
        $this->getPickupLocationByOrderId = $getPickupLocationByOrderId;
    }

    public function mycustommethod(int $orderId)
    {
        $pickupLocationCode = $this->getPickupLocationByOrderId->execute($orderId);
    }
}
```